# Преобразовать TSTRING в LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, windows, строки, unicode, typedef

Есть такое определение:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef std::wstring tstring
#else
    typedef std::wstring tstring
#end if
```

Потом имею такой код:

```
tstring str = TEXT("cd My_Folder");
LPCTSTR lpStr = str.c_str();

#ifdef UNICODE
    _wsystem(lpStr);
#else
    system(lpStr);
#endif
```

Однако, программа падает. Есть подозрение, что неправильно делаю конверсию строк. Подскажите, как нужно.

Comment: При наличии или отсутствии `UNICODE` падает? `LPCTSTR` опирается на `_UNICODE` (с подчеркиванием).

Comment: @alexolut, падает при наличии UNICODE. И если поменять на _UNICODE, вообще не собирается.

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильно. Нужно так:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef std::wstring tstring
#else
    typedef std::string tstring
#end if
```

У вас вместо `std::string` оба раза `std::wstring`.

---

И у вас либо должны быть определены **оба** макроса `UNICODE` и `_UNICODE`, либо ни один из них. Иначе ждите проблем.